# RamdaJS: After an object operation my keys are getting re-ordered alphabetically? Expected?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, ramda.js

This seems to happen with quite a few Ramda functions I am using. As an example I am reading the documentation for `mergeAll`:
https://ramdajs.com/docs/#mergeAll

Documentation example states:

```
R.mergeAll([{foo:1},{bar:2},{baz:3}]); //=> {foo:1,bar:2,baz:3}
```

This is what I **want**!

If I try the exact same command in the Ramda REPL:

https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?R.mergeAll%28%5B%7Bfoo%3A1%7D%2C%7Bbar%3A2%7D%2C%7Bbaz%3A3%7D%5D%29%3B

The output is:
`{"bar": 2, "baz": 3, "foo": 1}`

The object keys are getting sorted alphabetically. Is this expected behaviour and the documentation is incorrect?

Am trying to do something right now where the key order is fairly important and this alphabetical sorting is proving an issue! :(

Comment: Property ordering is not really under the control of the JavaScript program. The runtime has an ordering it follows per spec, but it's not sound design practice (in my opinion) to rely on it because it's not really meaningful; it's more about object lifecycle history.

Comment: It *is* possible for software to add properties in a particular order so that they look sorted, but if the object changes later that apparent ordering can change too.

Comment: If you need an ordered list, you need an array (or set)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's simply an artifact of the REPL output formatting.

[Another version](https://ramdajs.com/repl/?v=0.26.1#?console.log%28R.mergeAll%28%5B%7Bfoo%3A1%7D%2C%7Bbar%3A2%7D%2C%7Bbaz%3A3%7D%5D%29%29) that uses `console.log` shows that they are really in the order you expect.  However, I emphatically agree with Pointy that one should avoid counting on this order for pretty much anything.

The Ramda team [has discussed](https://github.com/ramda/ramda/issues/1067#issuecomment-135923353) actually ordering the keys alphabetically when it creates objects to avoid a certain class of errors. It's controversial, and no decision has been made on that even after several years.